# What's wrong with my CSS font-face linkage and usage

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, fonts, razor-pages

**EDIT**: So, for some reason, when setting font in "body" or "html" it didn't applied font to elements in "form", because I had only form element to test form elements, fonts didn't worked. When I just added some random text before "form" element by rolling my head on my keyboard, I found out that fonts are actually working... But I was expecting that if I set font-family rule in "body" or "html" every element will inherit that font... No CSS with "@font-face" rule needed editing...

So I have a problem with self-hosted font. I want to load Unscii font on my page, I've generated CSS file with @font-face rule and fonts (WOFF, WOFF2, TTF), linked that CSS file to my page, but when I'm trying to use this font in other CSS file, it doesn't work. Also when I trying to use other font, sizing of elements on page changes slightly, like "margins or paddings or content box", but the font face itself is still remains the same, even for "built-in" fonts. I've did everything same as in my other project where everything loaded and linked same, searched in Google, but every result refers to how link and use, so it didn't helped me.

This is how I link font-face CSS

```html
    <link href="fonts/unscii-16.woff2" rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin/>
    <link href="css/unscii.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

And this is my "unscii.css" file

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'unscii';
    src: url('../fonts/unscii-16.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/unscii-16.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/unscii-16.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

I'm using Razor Pages and ASP.NET Core 6, HTML code is located in _Layout.cshtml and works perfectly for all pages, only issue with fonts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help. you can remove the '' from URL and format as an OpenType because in my styling it is working that way!

you also can check this article.
https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7627

Check this out!

```
<link href="fonts/unscii-16.woff2?v=4.5.0" rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2"  crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

CSS file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: unscii;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  url(../fonts/unscii-16.woff2) format('opentype'),
}

@font-face {
  font-family: unscii;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(../fonts/unscii-16.ttf) format("opentype");
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Unscii;
}
```

Comment: I've found out "my" problem and edited the question

Comment: I have read your edited question and I was also looking on google because I have seen this for the first time. and I have found one thing it might help please have a look at a solution.

Comment: No, the font was already preloaded in link element. I fixed all font issues by just specifing font-family rule for all my form elements (such as button, textfields, etc.)

Comment: I see which means there is something else which is disturbing :) can you share SS how does text look at the moment I tried but in my project it was working so :)

Comment: How it looks now is [here](https://imgur.com/a/sH8OGIT). Still, it's better if I could define font in body and it will be applied everywhere. And also would be better if I could disable antialiasing and make font more pixelated

Comment: it is possible I have checked the image! is your website is live somewhere where I can inspect the body tag?

Comment: No, it's localhost, [this](https://imgur.com/a/KnchhBl) is body tag, fonts worked only until "form" element, inside "form" fallback or idk fonts were used, I've specified font-family rule for "input", "button" and font started working in those elements, everywhere font is being inherited from body (like divs, lists, links, etc.)

Comment: Try this out pest this in your CSS and let's see what will be the result :) because I check the body tags of my website and in the body and html tag I had this font-family

Comment: I've tried to set font in html as well, but it also didn't worked

Comment: This helped me solve a huge problem!